# differentiating two files and getting the unique output in third one

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, diff

I'm very new to shell scripting and learning it now.

I have two files.

File 1:

```
1   StartInstall, CDM_2.5B263, OK       
2   EndInstall, CDM_2.5B263, SUCCESS    
3   StartPatch, CDM_2.5.0.2B1, OK       
4   StartPatch, CDM_2.5.0.3B1, OK       
5   EndPatch, CDM_2.5.0.3B1, SUCCESS
```

File 2:

```
1   StartInstall, CDM_2.5B263, OK       
2   EndInstall, CDM_2.5B263, SUCCESS    
4   StartPatch, CDM_2.5.0.3B1, OK       
5   EndPatch, CDM_2.5.0.3B1, SUCCESS
```

I should find the difference in file 2 compare to file 1.
If any line missing, shell script should indicate the the missed line and write it in another text file (ex `result.txt`).
Shell script should also indicate me that the missed line lies between which two lines.

For example the output should be like in `Error.txt`
Line missing:

```
3   StartPatch, CDM_2.5.0.2B1, OK
```

Between 2 and 4

Answer (score 2):

Using `comm`, since the files are sorted:

```
comm -3 file1 file2 > result.txt
```

The output contains the lines that are present in `file1` but not `file2`, and also the lines that are present in `file2` but not `file1` prefixed with a tab.

If the files aren't sorted, sort them first. Assuming that you're using bash, ksh or zsh and not plain `sh`:

```
comm -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2) > result.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but comm is used for a sorted file , how do i sort these files ?

Comment: @Parulkusmatia The files in your question are sorted. If the real files aren't, run `sort` first.

Comment: done that , but it is not giving me the output i need

Comment: Can you please tell me what to do when i have multiple enteries missing in file 2 and some extra enteries, what can be used then ?  @Gilles

Comment: Can you please tell me what to do when i have multiple enteries missing in file 2 and some extra enteries, what can be used then ? @phk

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the easiest way. Notice `<` is an omission and `|` indicates a character in the line is different. (Line 5 in `file1.txt` had some whitespace characters missing in your copy-paste).

$ `diff -y file1.txt file2.txt > diff.txt`

```
1   StartInstall, CDM_2.5B263, OK                               1   StartInstall, CDM_2.5B263, OK
2   EndInstall, CDM_2.5B263, SUCCESS                            2   EndInstall, CDM_2.5B263, SUCCESS
3   StartPatch, CDM_2.5.0.2B1, OK                             <
4   StartPatch, CDM_2.5.0.3B1, OK                               4   StartPatch, CDM_2.5.0.3B1, OK
5   EndPatch, CDM_2.5.0.3B1, SUCCESS                          | 5   EndPatch, CDM_2.5.0.3B1, SUCCESS
```

This doesn't output a new file, but you get a vimdiff session that visually compares the two files and highlights the missing lines and characters very intuitively.

$ `vimdiff file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: Hi , this is not solving my problem, the files i posted here are just a small example. What actually i want to is to have a third file in which all the missed and extra enteries can be seen from file1 (file1 is the master file )

Comment: How does it not solve your problem? Clarify.

Comment: The files i pasted here are very small, and clearly the diff is seen, from vim, diff and simple comm. But i need to see what is missed from file2 and in what sequence it is missed , like what shud be above and below it . This thing has to be compared from fike1. I am taking base as file1.